# Do I use kinetic energy or momentum to figure out the final velocity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Let's say hypothetically that a gun fires a bullet which has a mass of 1 gram and a $V_\mathrm{initial}$ of 10 m/s, which becomes lodged in a wooden block that has a mass of 9 grams and is initially at rest. The impact causes the block (with the lodged bullet) to travel at a velocity $V_\mathrm{final}$. What is $V_\mathrm{final}$?

I'm confused. I don't know whether I should use momentum or kinetic energy to figure out the $V_\mathrm{final}$. I plugged in the numbers to both equations, and the resulting values of $V_\mathrm{final}$ didn't agree.

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/270871/when-to-use-conservation-of-energy-vs-conservation-of-momentum

Answer (score -2):

Okay, lets start this off with a simple answer, you can solve it many ways using fundamental algebra, that includes work energy, kinematic-dynamic and Impulse momentum theorem. I personally check myself with both. We can go into more detail later if we need so.

I personally use Work-energy-kinematic ways. However, we can start however by using Impulse-momentum theorem, just to make this short

Fnet * t = m * (change in) Velocity.

now, we can just say that the impulse that will produced on impact is 0.01 N*s
the impact will result in mass combined of 0.01kg's, thus 0.01N*s/0.01kg is 1 m/s resultant velocity.

We however, can use energy to find velocity after v=(square root) 2(KE)/mass

Comment: How do you account for the energy dissipated in heat, sound of impact, tearing of wood/lead?

Answer (score -3):

You can think of the problem this way: You can just divide the velocity by mf/mi or (9+1)/1, or 10/1, which is the same as multiplying the initial velocity by 1/10, which is the amount of mass that the motion energy is changing to apply to, which gives 1 m/s final velocity.

Comment: How does this address the OP question? You don't talk about any conservation principle.

Comment: But was I wrong? The final velocity is scaled by the initial velocity and the ratio of the initial mass to the final mass, because the momentum is velocity times mass, so `vf = vi*(mi/mf)` or as I originally put it `vf=vi/(mf/mi)`. Therefore, the final velocity is `1 m/s`.

Comment: OP did not ask about conservation. Boy, I sure love getting downvoted for posting a correct answer, gotta love StackExchange.