# Velocity of a block attached to a spring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, spring

Two blocks of mass $m$ are attached to a spring of spring constant $k$. One of the blocks is compressed by $x_0$ and then released. The question is, what is the velocity of the block when the spring reaches its natural length. I calculated the velocity by two methods:

1. By energy conservation
   $$-\frac{1}{2}k{x_0}^2+\frac{1}{2}mv^2+\frac{1}{2}mv^2=0$$
2. Using Force
   $$-kx=ma=mv\frac{dv}{dx}$$

Integrating from $x_0$ to $0$, we get
$$-\frac{1}{2}k{x_0}^2+\frac{1}{2}mv^2=0$$

It is clear that the $1^{st}$ method is correct but I am not able to understand at what step exactly the second method wrong?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117678/discussion-on-question-by-forester-velocity-of-a-block-attached-to-a-spring).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use Conservation of Energy vs Conservation of Momentum](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/270871/when-to-use-conservation-of-energy-vs-conservation-of-momentum)